# С чего начинать изучать docker?

Tags: linux, docker, развертывание, ос

Сегодня почти не осталось проектов где нет doker.
Из этого встал вопрос изучения данной технологии.
Подскажите как плавно и правильно его изучить, по шагам?

Comment: Не плохая книга «Использование Docker» Эдриен Моуэт. Правда материал слегка устаревший, но многие концепции не особо поменялись. Да иобзор инфраструктуры хороший.
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/139411597/

Comment: [по-английски](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) и [по-русски](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker)

Comment: Могу порекомендовать вот это [курс](https://stepik.org/course/1612/syllabus). Достаточно современный, охватывает все необходимое, чтобы начать работать с ним.

Comment: Спасибо, а надо платить что-то, что бы посмотреть эти видео?

Comment: Спасибо. Книгу получил, осталось найти время на ее прочтение.

Comment: Нет, Stepik бесплатная платформа